# echarts4r: horizontal jitter with discrete x axis

Tags: r, scatter-plot, jitter, echarts4r

In an echarts4r scatter plot, is it possible to add *horizontal jitter* with a *discrete* x axis?

```
library(echarts4r)
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(x = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"),
       y = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5),
       z = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5))

df |> 
  e_charts(x) |>
  e_scatter(y, symbol_size = 15) |>
  e_scatter(z, symbol_size = 15, symbol="diamond", jitter_amount = 1) |>
  e_color(
    c("red", "blue")
  )
```

The jitter option adds vertical jitter (blue diamonds) instead of the desired horizontal jitter.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could set `x_index = 1` to your `e_scatter` and use a second x axis with should not be shown to get the jitter of your points like this:

```r
library(echarts4r)
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(x = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"),
             y = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5),
             z = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5))

df |> 
  e_charts(x) |>
  e_scatter(y, symbol_size = 15) |>
  e_scatter(z, symbol_size = 15, symbol="diamond", jitter_amount = 2, x_index = 1) |>
  e_color(
    c("red", "blue")
  ) |>
  e_x_axis(index = 1, show=F)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This still adds the jitter on the y (vertical, continuous) dimension, though, and also produces an offset on the x (horizontal, discrete) dimension. I'm looking for a solution that shows the actual/precise values on the y dimension and adds jitter on the x dimension, so that the two instances of x=b and y=3 in the example can be distinguished.